# How do you represent 153 into base $\frac{-3}{2}$?

Tags: number-theory

How do you represent 153 into base $\frac{-3}{2}$?
I am taking a  number theory course.

I understand this example because I need to apply $$n_{1}=s(\frac{n_{0}-a_{0}}{r})$$.
As a matter of fact, in this example I am looking to find $n_{k}=0$.
In this case I think that $n_{0=153}$ ,$s=2$

If $r=3$ the possible remainders are 0,1 and 2.

So $a_{0}$ can be any of those remainders.

I am biased $r=-3$, because I am not sure if I can take the minus sign.
Which are the possible remainders for  $r=-3$?
I m struggling when r takes negative values. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure about you need to represent $(153)_{-\frac{5}{3}}$?What's the definition  that you're using?

Comment: I  know two fact: you can use find $(153)_{\frac{5}{3}}$ and you can find for example $(153)_{-3}$ but, what is you definition of $(x)_{b}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: That´s an exercise for my number theory course. This is a really easy example to solve with positive r values. But in this case, I m struggling because the minus.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but what is the definition of _fractional-negative-expansion_?

Comment: those are intergers for r and s

Comment: I have an idea but I am not sure. The possible remainders for r=−3 are 0,+-1.+-2. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok, I know this: Let $b>1$ be a real number. The $b-$expansion of a nonnegative real number $x$ is a representation $x=\sum_{0}^{n}a_{i}b^{i}$ where the $a_{i}$ are nonnegative integers less than $b$. I know also, if $b\geq 2$ and you can take $-b$ and to do $x=\sum_{0}^{n}a_{i}(-b)^{i}$  where each digit $a_{i}$ is an integer from $0$ to $b -1$ and the leading digit $a_{n} > 0$ (unless $n = 0$).

Comment: You mean it is a complex base?. But it looks different from $a+b_{i}$.

Comment: You can use $b>1, b \in \mathbb{R}$. I don't speak about the complex base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115934/discussion-between-ramanujan-and-charlie-van-basten-oydne).

Comment: Well. Thank you so much. But I m going to try bymyself for a while. Dont worry